# How to sort your blogposts as per their view count?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I want to sort all my `blogposts` as per their `view count`. For example, the `blogpost` which is viewed most, should come on top. But on my `blogger dashboard`, I don't see any option to sort the posts as per their `view count`. Is there any alternate way for this?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @Gowtham - okay, but it is disappointing :(. I have asked very basic thing which blogspot should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's possible.** This can be done within `YourBlogger > Stats > Posts`. It even supports ordering posts by their pageviews per `day/week/month/all-time` in your [Blogger Dashboard](https://www.blogger.com/home).

Check out [my blogger posts](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7960584883938241169#postsstats) ordered by pageviews.

[image]

Comment: @herohuyongtao but it shows only 10 post what about remains?

Comment: As of August 2023, the method described by here, is no longer valid (i.e., there is no such sort mechanism, anymore, though, at least, for the blogger, it would be nice!).

Answer (score 1):

By default,blogger posts are sorted as per date. Latest one at top.

There is no automatic way of sorting as per views.You can tell the blogger the Engineers to make such a feature in the suggestion topic at the official blogger product forums.Though,I see remote chances of such a feature.

However,here is a lengthy manual trick.

You can know which post has the most views with the Top 10 viewed posts widget or you can see them in the posts layout.Now,to change the order,go to each post and change the date manually.

Comment: @Michel - Its not a good solution and idea of changing the dates of the post is horrible.